# pro-verb (Many people answered that saving money made them happier than eating healthy did.)

Tags: proverbs

> Many people answered that saving money made them happier than eating healthy did.

Does the pro-verb 'did' mean "made them happy", and, thus, " ~ happier than eating healthy made them happy"? Or, Does it mean " ~ happier than eating healthy happier"?

Comment: It means the first one. Your second suggestion doesn't make sense.

Comment: healthy is an adjective and here looks like modifying eating, which means 'adverb', right?

Comment: Yes, it should properly be _eating healthily_ or _eating a healthy diet_.

Comment: eating healthy is like a colloquialism?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-eat-healthy-or-eat-healthily